# Redirect output from a command within a batch file whose output is already redirected?

Tags: php, windows, scripting, batch-file

I've searched high and low, but all the suggestions and tips I've found do not work for some reason.  I have a batch file that is being invoked as such:

```
cmd /C "automateMyProgram.bat >> automation.log 2>>&1"
```

That works great:  automation.log gets loaded with all the stdout and stderr for that particular batch file.  However, within that batch script I have the following command:

```
start php updateDB.php param1 param2 ^> updateDB.log
```

The php script does get executed just fine and reads in the parameters just fine, but updateDB.log is never created.  I ensured that php error reporting in the php.ini file is set to output errors to the command line interface.  There are several echo statements within the php script that I need to have recorded to a log, but they are not being output for some reason.  I read that if you use the start command to invoke a program, you must use the caret operator to redirect output since the program is started in a new process.  I also tried:

```
start php updateDB.php param1 param2 >> updateDB.log
```

and that didn't work either.  So I then tried:

```
start /B "Database Update" "php" "param1" "param2" >> updateDB.log
```

and that didn't work from within the batch file, but it did when I copy and pasted it directly into a cmd window on the desktop.

Might any of you know how I can redirect the output of the php script being called from a batch file?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the simplest solution:

```
start cmd /c "php updateDB.php param1 param2 > updateDB.log"
```

or, if you want to include error messages in updateDB.log,

```
start cmd /c "php updateDB.php param1 param2 > updateDB.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution!

Comment: +1 I also had problem with redirecting output, e.g. `start app.exe param > log 2>&1`. Your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code that worked in a BATCH file launching VBScripts with the START command. It will lauch the seperate process and put the results into the specified log file.

```
rem **Setting the passed device to run against to a varible**
SET Audit_Device=%1

rem     **Launching "_SomeScript.vbs" in a seperate window**
start "WindowTitle" /d%~dp0  cmd /C cscript.exe ^"%~dp0_SomeScript.vbs^" %Audit_Device% ^>^"%~dp0%Audit_Device%_SomeScriptLogFile.txt^"

rem       **Launching "ListPermissionsForAllShares-Basic-and-Detailed.vbs" in a seperate window**
start "List Share Permission" /d%~dp0  cmd /C cscript.exe ^"%~dp0ListPermissionsForAllShares-Basic-and-Detailed.vbs^" %Audit_Device% ^>^"%~dp0%Audit_Device%_Share_Permissions.txt^"
```