# Re-direct output of command within a script whose output is re-directed

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Suppose that a script of mine is invoked like this:

```
(script.sh 1>&2) 2>err
```

Is there a way to re-direct the output of one of the commands run by the script to *standard output*? I tried to do `2>&1` for that command, but that did not help. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9386011/2725810) suggests a solution for `Windows` command shell and re-directs to a file instead of the standard output.

For a simple example, suppose that the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... many commands whose output will go to `stderr`
echo aaa # command whose output needs to go to `stdout`; tried 2>&1  
# ... many commands whose output will go to `stderr`
```

How do I cause the output of that `echo` to go to `stdout` (a sign of that would be that it would appear on the screen) when the script is invoked as shown above?

Comment: Please show more information.

Comment: @123 I added an example.

Comment: You could use `echo Hi > /dev/tty` if you want it to go explicitly to the screen.

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, I meant that it needs to go to `stdout`.

Comment: The last sentence in your question is wrong then ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Fixed.

Comment: You could echo to `fd 3` using `>&3 echo Hi` and direct that to the screen.

Comment: What is fd 3? The purpose is that it goes to `stdout`, since the script that invokes my script is listening to `stdout`.

Comment: You redirect everything that comes out of the script to stderr though,,. Direct it to >&3 then redirect 3>&1 after the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send it to stderr in the script

```
echo this goes to stderr
echo so does this
echo this will end up in stdout >&2
echo more stderr
```

Run as

```
 { ./script.sh 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 ; } 2>err
```

err contains

```
this goes to stderr
so does this
more stderr
```

Output to stdout

```
this will end up in stdout
```

Comment: Is 3 here like `temp` in `swap`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No, its just a file descriptor, this just points it to where stderr(&2) points to. I think there is a better way of switching descriptors but i can't remember how to do it.

Comment: I think the answer to the question I meant to ask is "yes". It is just like swapping two pointers in `c++` :) Excellent and works!