# Have `make` echo to standard error without re-direction?

Tags: bash, makefile

Some of the targets in my `Makefile` run programs whose output (which they send to `stdout`) I am interested in. For a reason not known to me, the authors of `make` decided to echo the executed commands to `stdout`, which pollutes the latter.

A hard way around this problem that involves swapping file descriptors was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37297490/2725810). I am wondering if there is a simpler way to force `make` echo to `stderr`.

I looked through the `man` page of `make`, but did not find anything to this end besides the `-s` option. I prefer to preserve the echo of commands, but have it in `stderr`.

I also tried making an auxiliary target (which I made a prerequisite of all other targets), in which I put:

```
exec 3>&2
exec 2>&1
exec 1>&3
```

but bash complained that 3 wasn't a valid file descriptor. I tried only `exec 1>&2`, but that did not have any effect...

Comment: Even if you do that, your terminal will still be 'polluted' with the output of `make`.

Comment: I want to call `make` from a script, which then would process the output of the mentioned programs. Also, I would just re-direct `stderr` to a file, which I can view later if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The reason make shows the command line on stdout is because that's what the POSIX standard for make requires, and 30+ years of history expect.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html and search for the section on "STDOUT".

You cannot modify the file descriptors in the make program from within a recipe, because the recipe is run in a subshell: any changes you make to the file descriptors only take effect in the subshell.  It's not possible in UNIX for a child process to modify the file descriptors of its parent.

Similarly, each *line* in a recipe in make is run in a *different* subshell.  If you want to do fancy things like redirect output for a recipe you'll have to write it all on one line:

```
exec 3>&2; exec 2>&1; exec 1>&3; <my command here>
```

Of course if you intend to do this a lot I would put that in a make variable and use that variable instead.

There is no way to get make to write its output to stderr instead of stdout, unless you want to modify the source code for GNU make and use the version you build yourself instead.  It would actually be straightforward to do this as long as you're using a newer version of GNU make (4.0 and above) since all output is generated from one plase (in `output.c`).

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful!

Comment: "There is no way to get make to write its output to stderr instead of stdout." It turns out that there is :) See my answer.

Comment: No, make is still writing its output to stdout.  You've just redirected its stdout to a different file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do entirely in the `Makefile` is this:

```
define REDIR
@printf 1>&2 "%s\n" '$(1)'; $(1)
endef

.PHONY: all
all:
        $(call REDIR,echo updating .stamp)
        $(call REDIR,touch .stamp)
```

That is to say, take control of the command echoing yourself via a macro. Unfortunately, it involves writing your recipe lines as `$(call ...) syntax.

`REDIR` now implements the semantics of echoing the command, and executing it, via macro expansion.

The `1>&2` is Bash-specific syntax for duplicating the standard error file descriptor to standard out, so the command then effectively prints to standard output.

Test run:

```
$ make
echo updating .stamp
updating .stamp
touch .stamp

$ make 2> /dev/null
updating .stamp
```

As you can see, `updating .stamp`, which is the output of our explicitly coded `echo` line, nicely goes to standard output. The commands are implicitly sent to standard error.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pollute the output of echo of what make produces, can't you simply run

```
make -n >&2 && make -s
```

This is the sample Makefile:

```
all:
    ls
    echo done
```

Here is the output of `make`:

> ```
> ls
> Makefile
> echo done
> done
> ```

Here is output of `make -n >&2 && make -s`:

> ```
> ls
> echo done
> Makefile
> done
> ```

Naturally, output of either step can be redirected to file.

Comment: This way I will not know which command produced which output. In particular, for the targets that actually do compilation, if there are compile errors, I will not know which compilation commands resulted in an error. This can be a serious problem for a script that invokes `make` multiple times and `stderr` is analyzed retroactively.

Comment: Note that stdout and stderr are not synchronized anyway. So, if you see `ls\necho abc\necho def` - you cannot be sure if the second line is result of `ls` or a separate execution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following `Makefile`:

```
target-1:
    target-1-body
target-2:
    target-2-body
target-3:
    target-3-body
```

We change it as follows:

```
target-1-raw:
    target-1-body
target-2-raw:
    target-2-body
target-3-raw:
    target-3-body

%-raw:
    echo "Error: Target $@ does not exist!"    
%:
    @make $@-raw 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3
```

The invocation is same as before, e.g. `make target-1`.

With two additional targets we made `make` output to `stderr`.

**FYI:** I am [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324851/2725810) to develop this solution further so the user would not be able to invoke the raw targets directly.

Comment: First you should always use `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make, never raw `make`.  Second, this only works for targets which are "simple"; what if you had .o files that depended on .h and .cpp files and .a files that depended on .o files and binaries that depended on all the above, etc.  Are you going to rewrite your makefile so they all use these raw targets internally?  And lastly, you're invoking an entirely new instance of make for every target: that will slow down your build significantly if you have lots of targets.

Comment: @MadScientist 1. What is the difference between `make` and `$(MAKE)`? 2. Yes, all targets and dependencies need to be renamed. I agree that the change suggested by @Kaz is easier to automate. 3. No. Target dependencies are raw targets, so only one additional instance of `make` is run.

Comment: @AlexCohn Which version of `make` are you using? I checked that things are inherited, including the variables and the command-line arguments (tried both `-s` and setting variables on command line). Using version 3.81.

Comment: Please read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html#MAKE-Variable

Comment: @AlexCohn OK. But your last statement ("any command-line arguments") was too strong.

Comment: `$(MAKE)` invokes the same make executable that was parsing the makefile; also, it forwards the arguments from the "parent" command line. `@make` will look for the executable according to standard PATH, and the command-line arguments, e.g. `-n`, may not be inherited correctly.

Comment: **FYI:** I am trying to develop this solution further so the user would not be able to invoke the raw targets directly. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37324851/2725810

Answer (score 0):

Another posix-incompatible solution is to put

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&2; exec 2>&1; exec 1>&3;
```

into `helper/stderr` relative to my project, and

```
helperdir = helper
SHELL = BASH_ENV="$(helperdir)/stderr" /bin/bash
```

into my Makefile.

Now all executed rule code output is redirected to stderr file descriptor.

`BASH_ENV` environment variable does, if set to a script path, execute that script at every bash invocation.