# Checking whether a variable set by the parent exists

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

Suppose the following `Makefile` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308082/2725810) what it's good for):

```
target-1-raw:
    target-1-body
target-2-raw:
    target-2-body
target-3-raw:
    target-3-body

%-raw:
    echo "Error: Target $@ does not exist!"    
%:
    @$(MAKE) $@-raw 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3
```

I am trying to make sure that the user invoked it without the suffix `-raw`, i.e. like this:

```
make target-1
```

and **not** like this:

```
make target-1-raw
```

So, I would like to set a variable in the rule of the target `%` and check from all other targets that this variable was set:

```
check:
    #??? If FLAG is not set, then abort with an error message. 

target-1-raw: check
    target-1-body
target-2-raw: check
    target-2-body
target-3-raw: check
    target-3-body

%-raw:
    echo "Error: Target $@ does not exist!"    
%:
    #??? set FLAG
    @$(MAKE) $@-raw 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3
```

I tried various ways of implementing the lines starting with `#???` without success. If I use the facilities of `make` (such as `ifndef` and `ifeq`, then things seem to get evaluated not when I want them to). I tried to use the shell's `if []` also, but without success. So, if this is at all possible to achieve, then what tool is my friend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make sure that the user invoked it without the suffix `-raw`

I don't see what purpose is served by this.  `make` and Makefiles are tools aimed at people whom one normally relies upon to have some idea of what they are doing.  There is no particular reason to actively prevent users of your Makefile from performing a build *without* stream swapping, if that's what they really want.

> So, I would like to set a variable in the rule of the target % and check from all other targets that this variable was set.

Not possible.  Each logical line in a `make` recipe is executed by a separate shell.  The commands are shell commands, not `make` commands, and no variables you set via such commands survive the exit of the shell at the completion of the command.

> So, if this is at all possible to achieve, then what tool is my friend here?

The main mechanism by which a `make` recipe can record persistent information for subsequent commands or rules is by writing files.  The content of such files or even their mere existence can be used to influence subsequent commands.  For a job such as yours, however, that seems likely to be extremely fragile.  Nevertheless, it might look like this:

```
target-1-raw:
    temp='$@'; test -e $${temp%-raw}-check \
      || echo warning: target '$@' made directly
    target-1-body

%-raw:
    echo "Error: Target $@ does not exist!"    
%:
    touch $@-check
    @$(MAKE) $@-raw 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3
    rm $@-check
```

I assure you, however, that if I ever received a `Makefile` containing such a construct then I would not be impressed, and my first impulse would be to rip it out.  I suggest that you stop viewing your users' freedom as a problem to solve.

Comment: I guess I did not express myself well. I want to help the users. Instead of just writing about the intended usage in the documentation, I want to issue a warning. Abortion was just one example (may be not the most suitable one) of an action that can be taken.

Comment: Also, is it possible may be to export an environment variable to the parent shell of the parent `make`? Would the child `make` have access to such a variable?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the `Makefile` you present does not cause `make` to output to `stderr`, which indeed cannot be done without building a modified version.  Instead, it causes `make`'s `stdout` to be the shell's `stderr`, and *vise versa*.  This is a subtle but important difference.  The identities and states of the standard streams are an aspect of each process's execution environment; there is no universal `stdout`, etc..

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, no, you cannot use environment variables, as I already explained in my answer.  You can set environment variables in the shell launched to run a given command, but these affect only the environment of that command and any commands it spawns.  They are not visible in `make's` own environment, nor, therefore, in the environment of any other command that `make` runs.

Comment: The point is that the desired *behavior* was achieved. Here too I am looking to achieve a certain behavior. I would actually very much appreciate if you could show doing it with files as one way in an answer. I am guessing that one would want to `touch` a file with some obscure name in `/tmp` in this case...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I have added an example, as requested.  Do not make me regret it.

Comment: How would I make you regret it? It's so very cool! Though `$${temp%-raw}` is magic to me, so I am going to try learn about `$$` and `%`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, `$$` escapes the `$` so that it is not interpreted by `make`, but instead passed through to the shell.  The shell sees `${temp%-raw}`.  As for the `%`, read up on [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Thank you! Now I came to understand what you meant by the technique being fragile. It's about removing that file in case something wrong happens. Also, the targets on which the target for which `make` was called will always print a warning. So, I will heed your initial advice :)